# Dell Latitude E5470 heating up, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dell, laptop, ssd, overheating

Newbie here, I installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday, and since then I noticed that the right side of the laptop especially at the palm rest area is very warm, my right hand is always sweating. I didn't had this problem with Windows 10. I read someone had a similar problem and a user suggested to add noatime,nodiratime in fstab. I did that as well, sadly the problem is still here. I installed psensor to check the temperature and my ssd is at 40 degrees celsius.
Does anyone got an idea what causes this?